# dropping 1 events on the floor

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat

I'm getting the following warning message on `logcat` before the device restarts:

```
10-15 15:16:15.789: WARN/SensorService(110): dropping 1 events on the floor
```

Does anyone know what does this message means and whether it has anything to do with restarting the device?

Answer (score 1):

I think this message comes when a very high CPU utilization. What are you doing with your device?

Comment: I'm trying to deploy/test/debug a new android app using eclipse. do you mean CPU utilization of the device? how do you read the cpu utilization of an android phone?

Comment: Yes CPU utilization of the device. In the task manager of your device can you read the cpu utilization. At Android 4.0 there are more development settings, including CPU utilization.

Comment: Thanks, but I need more information on what exactly is causing this warning message, and why it restarts my device? do you have any links or references i can read?